# Replace word with the same amount of spaces

Tags: vb.net, replace

How can I replace a word (p.g in `ListBox`) with the same number of spaces (as letters)?

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string constructor:

```
dim s as string = "1234"
s = New String(" ", s.length)
```

With a listbox, you might want to consider removing the item instead of setting it to spaces:

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
```

Here's one way to remove an arbitrary word from a string s:

```
sRemove = "abc"
i = s.IndexOf(sRemove)
If i >= 0 Then s = s.Substring(0, i) & New String(" ", sRemove.Length) & s.Substring(i + sRemove.Length)
```

Comment: no, I want  the to replace certain word with the same same amount of spaces. How can I use your code according to ListBox?

Comment: Which word do you want to replace?

Comment: A lot of words... I need to count how many spaces are there and replace them with spaces.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you need. I've edited the answer to replace only a specified word.